# Overnight issue with pandas datetime

Tags: pandas

```
pairs = ['DX=F']
data = yf.download(pairs,'2022-01-01')['Adj Close']
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data.plot(figsize=(23,8), color='red')
plt.axhline(100.0, color='yellow')
plt.ylabel('Prices')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.legend(['US Dollar Index'])
plt.show()
```

```
dollar = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
dollar
```

```
Date                            Adj Close
2022-01-03 00:00:00-05:00   96.210999
2022-01-04 00:00:00-05:00   96.274002
2022-01-05 00:00:00-05:00   96.181999
2022-01-06 00:00:00-05:00   96.325996
2022-01-07 00:00:00-05:00   95.722000
```

'Overnight error, first time I've encountered the timestamp, yesterday when calling the dataframe object, the output was Date and Adj Close, without any time stamp as above, is there a way to resolve this?'

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: There is no error report to include......the question is mores specific to obtaining the necessary output when calling the dataframe object, in the above snippet of code example, I want to remove the timestamp from the dataframe...

Comment: If you want to delete the timestamp from the dataframe, use `dollar.reset_index(drop=True)` or `dollar.drop(columns=['Date'])` (can't tell from your post what your dataframe looks like). Else, I'm having trouble understanding your question. What does the data (in `data` or `dollar`) look like? What is your desired result? What did you do to achieve it?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. My desired result is to be able to seperate or remove from the Date index the time stamp that is now showing. If I drop the index, I will lose the Date which I need further down the line when plotting plots for visualization that require the date index.

Comment: dollar is just an int used to store the DataFrame, when calling the dollar, the DataFrame presents price data for Open, Close etc. But is now lncluding a timestamp, yesterday this was not the case, the Date index presented the date only!!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you would like to get just the date portion of the 'Date' column, so e.g. convert then entry 2022-01-03 00:00:00-05:00   to 2022-01-03, is this correct?  To provide a valid answer, what is the data type of the date column?  If it is a pandas datetime stamp, you just need to parse the date if it is a str then you need to create a datetime stamp and parse the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to extract just the date from a dataframe index which is in the form '2022-01-03 00:00:00-05:00'. So for example in the above sample you would be left withy 2022-01-03 as the index.

Given a dataFrame of the following:

```
                            Adj Close
2022-01-03 00:00:00-05:00   96.210999
2022-01-04 00:00:00-05:00   96.274002
2022-01-05 00:00:00-05:00   96.181999
2022-01-06 00:00:00-05:00   96.325996
2022-01-07 00:00:00-05:00   95.722000
```

Convert the index to a date column by:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).date
```

Which yields:

```
            Adj Close
2022-01-03  96.210999
2022-01-04  96.274002
2022-01-05  96.181999
2022-01-06  96.325996
2022-01-07  95.722000
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the above example you have provided as per below: '2022-01-03 00:00:00-05:00 - I would like to remove this part '00:00:00-05:00' from the pandas data frame. I've never seen this before when using the yahoo finance api, so I'm not sure how to get rid of it. This is my problem!!!

Comment: The answer provided does exactly that.  It leaves only the date element in the timestamp, although if you are using Pandas, I really don't understand why you need to do that.

Comment: Can you provide the example using my lines of code above, because the code provided didn't allow me to do exactly that..

Comment: simply replace the line ```data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)``` with ```data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index).dt.date```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: Its not working when I adjust the code to reflect your solution.

Comment: What is not working?  Please explain.  Show what you are getting versus what you expect

Comment: Let me check the example code - I may have missed this!